# Google maps add rectangular border to custom marker

Tags: javascript, css, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google maps api,

I have tried with multiple markers with info windows added successfully 
and now i want to add the border to the particular custom marker,
i am struggling for a custom marker with border

this is the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/pGBZD/

and this my code edited :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"  type="text/javascript"></script>

</head> 

<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 1500px; height: 1400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var locations = [
                            ['STHOWBGA01_ATIF_RNID_L015',24.31026,93.56268],
                            ['SWKHMRID01_BILF_RNID_L039',25.65182,91.62737],
                            ['SMOKZUNB01_GTLF_RNID_L006',26.019,94.53],
                            ['SDIMSGRN01_ATCF_RNID_L023',25.8271,93.6853],
                            ['SKOHKRMA01_BILF_RNID_L010',25.5815,94.21959],
                            ['SMOKANGB01_BILF_RNID_L001',26.214,94.6876],
                            ['SDIMDIM087_ATIF_TTID_L026',25.8939,93.7602],
                            ['SWKHLYNKI1_GTLF_RNID_L061',25.5041,91.6109],
                            ['SIMWIMP109_ATCF_TTOD_L047',24.83982,93.97707],
                            ['SDIMZLUKI2_ATCF_RNID_L017',25.63998,93.66512],
                            ['GWTRTLMUR5_BILF_RNOD_L039',23.841,91.6202],
                            ['GWTRKLBRI1_BILF_RNOD_L017',23.50866,91.26185],
                            ['GWTRBXNGR1_BILF_RNOD_L033',23.61268,91.17243],
                            ['GWTRAGR101_BILF_TTOD_L055',23.8655,91.25584],
                            ['GWTRBIS007_BILF_RNOD_L022',23.6785,91.2963],
                            ['GWTRGOK004_BILF_RNOD_L023',23.70692,91.27397],
                            ['GWTRBLWBN1_BILF_RNOD_L038',24.0179,91.4529],
                            ['SJOWKHL007_ATIF_RNOD_L012',25.35197,92.3723],
                            ['TTINNMSAI4_VIOF_RNID_L011',27.66616,95.87926],
                            ['SIMWUKHRL5_VIOF_RNID_L061',25.12267,94.36558],
                            ['SDIMZLUKI3_BILF_RNOD_L035',25.63658,93.64943]

            ];


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.83982,93.97707),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And now for the Customer marker center (lat,long) i have  to add the rectangular box and marker init.

```
   ------------
   |          |
   |  marker  |
   |          |
   ------------
```

i dont have that much reputation to add images of google maps,

so please observe the above sample diagram with marker init and border with rectangular box.

**please let me know the how to add the rectangular box to the custom marker**

And now i am trying to plot the custom marker i.e.. center lat long with border ,

i am struggling to add a border to a particular custome marker and done lots of google in google api library also , this is the link :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

please help..

Thanks...

Comment: Why don't you create a custom image in the form of a rectangle with a pin in the center, and use it as your marker icon? Would you rather add a rectangle object that follows the marker around when dragged? I'd like to understand what's the intended functionality.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing work for you which is not the goal of this site.

Comment: yes i got an idea , i will do google...get png images ..with border ans marker init

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) around your marker.

or

2. Create a custom Marker [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon).

or

3. Create a custom Marker [Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol).

Comment: Why do you need that border? Did you consider using a disctinct marker icon for the specific marker? For example a marker of another color?

Comment: actually i done using the auto complete input text, if the user search for a particular lat long than it shows the marker on the google maps , and now according to requirement i have to add the border to the particular lat long border with blink...i am struggling for this since 10 days..please help

Comment: according to the particular site_id..i.e...in data  var locations = STHOWBGA01_ATIF_RNID_L015 in javascript code...the user select according to this site_id and plot on the google maps with marker..

Comment: yes...if a user search for a particular lat and long ...using auto complete it will mark on the maps with border rectangular with blink ..i.e.border blinking

Comment: *according to requirement i have to add the border to the particular lat long border with blink* I think you should propose another solution. For example, a marker of another color, with a [DROP or BOUNCE animation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations).

Comment: Yes, i know this and i am working on it ...how to add border rectangular box to that ..particular marker i.e.. bounce marker

Comment: No. You would need to create a Rectangle or Polygon. Both are based on bounds which will be difficult to implement (because changing the zoom level will affect the *size* of the box). There is one easy way to do it, user @amenadiel suggested in the first comment, which is: **create your own marker image that includes the border that you want**. IMO this will be ugly. You can find the default icon here: http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-poi.png&scale=1

Comment: oh, thanks so much i am looking for the Border blink icon with maker init ..i.e ... png file in online i have tried to load the image from online but it dint found any where..the link you provide me the same marker i am plotting default marker provided by the google maps...

Comment: if any blinking border with marker init png image is there in online please provide me the link ...